# Scraping a table from a .asp

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the main table of [this site](/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[4]). 
I don't have much knowledge in  web-development, but I have already scraped other websites following some tutorial.

As I haven't found anything specicficaly about .asp, I've tried to follow some tutorials, such as [this](http://blog.corynissen.com/2015/01/using-rvest-to-scrape-html-table.html).

However, when I run the following code, it returns an empty list. Why is this empty list returned an how can I get the tabble data?

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www2.aneel.gov.br/scg/gd/VerGD.asp?pagina=1&acao=buscar&login=&NomPessoa=&IdAgente=&DatConexaoInicio=&DatConexaoFim="

table<-url%>%
    read_html()%>%
    html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[4]")%>%
    html_table()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site has seriously malformed HTML which is causing `libxml2` (the C library behind `rvest` & `xml2` R packages) to choke on the parsing.

I ran:

```
htmltidy::tidy_html()
```

on just the unparsed HTML content from the site and it spit back:

```
## Tidy found 1551 warnings and 8 errors! Not all warnings/errors were shown.
```

with many lines noting that it had to throw away many table rows.

One big issue with the content is this:

[image]

(that's an illegal place to stick a `<form>`) and most of the other table rows are missing a starting `<tr>`. The person who coded that site should be barred from making any web content ever again in their life.

So, we have to edit the HTML before parsing. And, we can also support parameters for that main form while we're at it:

```
get_power_info <- function(pagina = 1L, acao = "buscar", login = "",
                     nom_pessoa = "", id_agente = "", dat_conexao_inicio = "",
                     dat_conexao_fim = "") {

  # we need alot of packages to make this work

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require("httr", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("xml2", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("rvest", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("janitor", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("stringi", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("dplyr", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  })

  # get the page like a browser

  httr::GET(
    url = "http://www2.aneel.gov.br/scg/gd/VerGD.asp",
    query = list(
      pagina = as.character(as.integer(pagina)),
      acao = acao,
      login = login,
      NomPessoa = nom_pessoa, 
      IdAgente = id_agente,
      DatConexaoInicio = dat_conexao_inicio,
      DatConexaoFim = dat_conexao_fim
    )
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # DON'T PARSE IT YET

  out <- httr::content(res, as = "text")

  # Remove beginning & trailing whitespace from lines

  l <- stri_trim_both(stri_split_lines(out)[[1]])

  # Now, remove all form-component lines and all blank lines

  l[-c(
    which(grepl("<form", l, fixed = TRUE)), 
    which(grepl("<input", l, fixed = TRUE)),
    which(l == "")
  )] -> l

  # Get the indices of all the <td> tags that should have a <tr> before them but dont

  to_fix <- c()
  for (i in 1:(length(l)-1)) {
    if (all(c(
      grepl("/tr", l[i]), grepl("td", l[i+1])
    ))) {
      to_fix <- c(to_fix, (i+1))
    }

  }

  # Fix them

  l[to_fix] <- sprintf("<tr>%s", l[to_fix])

  # NOW WE CAN PARSE IT

  x <- read_html(paste0(l, collapse="\n"))

  # Find the table in a less breakable way

  tabl <- html_nodes(x, xpath=".//table[@class = 'tabelaMaior']/tr/td[contains(., 'UNIDADES')]/../..")

  # Remove the useless title row that makes html_table() cry

  xml_remove(html_node(tabl, xpath=".//tr[1]"))

  # Remove the bottom pagination row that makes html_table() cry

  xml_remove(html_node(tabl, xpath=".//tr/td[@colspan = '20']/.."))

  # Extract the table with better column names

  xdat <- html_table(tabl, header=TRUE, trim=TRUE)[[1]] 
  xdat <- janitor::clean_names(xdat)
  xdat <- dplyr::tbl_df(xdat)

  xdat

}
```

Seeing it in action:

```
xdf <- get_power_info()
## # A tibble: 1,000 x 14
##    distribuidora    codigo_da_gd  titular_da_uc   classe subgrupo modalidade
##    <chr>            <chr>         <chr>           <chr>  <chr>    <chr>     
##  1 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… MARCELO FORTES… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  2 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… JOSE DE JESUS … Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  3 Companhia de El… GD.BA.000.04… MAURICIO FRAGO… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  4 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… VALTER CID MEN… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  5 COPEL DISTRIBUI… GD.PR.000.04… WALDEMAR PERES… Comer… B3       Geracao n…
##  6 CELG DISTRIBUIÇ… GD.GO.000.04… Alfredo Ambrós… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  7 CELG DISTRIBUIÇ… GD.GO.000.04… Reginaldo Rosa… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  8 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… LIVIO JEFFERSO… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
##  9 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… Francislene Me… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
## 10 Companhia Energ… GD.PI.000.04… LUISA MARIA MO… Resid… B1       Geracao n…
## # ... with 990 more rows, and 8 more variables:
## #   quantidade_de_u_cs_que_recebem_os_creditos <int>, municipio <chr>,
## #   uf <chr>, cep <chr>, data_conexao <chr>, tipo <chr>, fonte <chr>,
## #   potencia_instalada_k_w <chr>
```

NOTE: You'll likely want to actually scrape that pagination row first (before deleting it) to grab all the pagination links so you can repeat the scrape. I have no idea if the parameters work as expected but you kinda should do some work for this, too ;-)

Comment:  if it does fit the bill, it helps others who are searching for answers to know this worked by ticking the accept answer box on the answer.